# Want to create custom scroll animation in draggableScrollablesheet, but can't find a way

Tags: flutter, animation, flutter-animation

So, I was doing a flutter challenge, I have done 50 percent of the animations, but when I went to create a custom scroll animation on draggableScrollableSheet, where if the user slides the sheet upwards the items react with clamping and bouncing physics but I cannot figure that solution with draggablesheet as it lacks physics parameter.

You can check the video of the scroll animation to get a better idea [here](https://imgur.com/a/U7h9qI0) :

Anyhelp will be appreciated!

Suggestions on how to approach this scroll animation.

Comment: DraggableScrollableSheet widget doesn't have built-in support for custom physics like ClampingScrollPhysics or BouncingScrollPhysics. Maybe you can try it by combining various widgets and controllers to simulate the desired behavior. Lemme try an example solution.

Answer (score 0):

Your link is not working.
Here is a simplified example.

```
class CustomScrollableSheet extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _CustomScrollableSheetState createState() => _CustomScrollableSheetState();
}

class _CustomScrollableSheetState extends State<CustomScrollableSheet> {
  ScrollController _scrollController = ScrollController();
  double _scrollOffset = 0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return NotificationListener<ScrollUpdateNotification>(
      onNotification: (notification) {
        setState(() {
          _scrollOffset = _scrollController.offset;
        });
        return true;
      },
      child: DraggableScrollableSheet(
        initialChildSize: 0.5,
        minChildSize: 0.2,
        builder: (context, controller) {
          _scrollController = controller;
          return ListView.builder(
            controller: controller,
            itemCount: 50,
            itemBuilder: (context, index) => ListTile(
              title: Text('Item $index'),
            ),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

You can experiment with different values for `ClampingScrollPhysics`, `BouncingScrollPhysics`, and the damping factor to get the desired effect